# Asp.net http tunelling Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, httpwebrequest, http-tunneling

Is there any open source http tunneling software written in asp.net ? I know i can simply get http response and display it in an iframe, but this is not the result want. The links should be replaced, the styles of the page content should be set respectively. This needs lots of parsing and editing stuff. It would be great if there is an open source control or project that can do it for me. Unfortunately i couldn't find any on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to display content from a different domain in an asp.net page without using IFRAMES? If that's so, I don't think that is possible today.

There is; however, a jQuery plugin that allows you load content from other websites using JSONP+YQL. Se [here](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/) and [here.](http://www.wait-till-i.com/2010/01/10/loading-external-content-with-ajax-using-jquery-and-yql/)

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what i meant. sorry if i was not clear enough.I am checking the links you gave. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From your page's code behind, use the `System.Net.WebClient` to make a webrequest to the other site and then take the returned HTML and display it on your page.

**Edit:**
If you don't want to manually fix all of the HTML yourself, take a look at the [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting) module in IIS7.  It can act like a proxy and pull in content from other domains.

Comment: This sort of works, the problem is that all the stylesheets, link references, etc, will be broken unless all sylesheet references, javascript files, etc, are referenced using absolute paths instead of relative ones. I think that's why he said on his question: `This needs lots of parsing and editing stuff.`

Comment: @lcarus you are right. sorry if i was not very clear. Normally the brute force way of solving the problem is first take all the html page with the references it has and then take all the resources , update all the links in the page accordingly and finally show the page to the user. But i am trying to find out if there is some sort of shortcut for that. Thanks...